# PCManFM bookmarks not being respected by other applications

Tags: lubuntu, pcmanfm

I've just migrated from Lubuntu 12.10 to Lubuntu 13.04 and PCManFM bookmarks are not working properly.

Bookmarks work fine when on PCManFM but if you goto to Firefox, Chromium, Leafpad, LibreOffice or any other application and try to access your Bookmarks from those applications, I can see only an old set of bookmarks. It was not a really fresh install: I keep my /home in a separate partition, so /root and /swap are the fresh ones. The only fresh install was Lubuntu 11.10 sometime ago.

The file .gtk-bookmarks at my /home folder seems to be updated correctly from what I checked. So every bookmark changed on PCManFM is changed on that file.

More info: If I open Leafpad (it could be any other application except PCManFM), menu File>Open> and from that window I bookmark another folder, that folder won't be available  on Bookmarks at PCManFM but it will be available as a bookmarked folder on the other applications (Leafpad, Chromium and so on). Finally, when modifying PCManFM bookmarks from this window, the file .gtk-bookmarks at my /home folder will not be updated as expected, confirming the modification is not acknowledged by PCManFM but acknowledged by the other applications.

More info 2: besides the file .gtk-bookmarks at my /home folder, I noticed there's a file called bookmarks at /home/username/.config/gtk-3.0. So now I realise that my applications (Leafpad, LibreOffice, Chromium) are seeing that file inside that path and not seeing the file .gtk-bookmarks at my /home folder.

More info 3: I've just set up Lubuntu 13.04 fresh in a VM and I can see the same odd behaviour described above, so I'd say it looks like a bug on PCManFM dealing with GTK3. However I'm not a dev so I need confirmation.

Is that a bug or is it expected?

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to find a workaround. Looks like there's an issue with GTK 3.0 and PCManFM.

1. Rename `/home/username/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` to `bookmarks.old`
2. Make a symlink:

   ```
   ln -s /home/username/.gtk-bookmarks /home/username/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
   ```

   If the symlink does not survive a reboot, try the symlink with a period before the file name:

   ```
   ln -s /home/username/.gtk-bookmarks /home/username/.config/gtk-3.0/.bookmarks
   ```

   Kind of odd though that the symlink did not survive without the period:

You can find more info at the bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pcmanfm/+bug/1208681